# Black spot removal from original image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am having few images in which there is a small 4-5 pixel black spot/contour which I want to remove from the original image and save the new removed contour image.
For the same I have tried many ways but at the end I am getting binary image only with removed contour.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
input_image = Image.open(path_to_image)
input_array = np.asarray(input_image)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(input_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(b_img, 128, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,3)
mask = cv2.inRange(thresh, 30, 255)
cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
# # print(cnts)
rect_areas = []
for c in cnts:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    rect_areas.append(w * h)
# print(rect_areas)
avg_area = mean(rect_areas)
for c in cnts:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cnt_area = w * h
    if cnt_area < 1000:
        mask[y:y + h, x:x + w] = 0
cv2.imwrite("img.jpg",mask)
```

Over here I am getting binary image can someone help me to store original image with 3 channels and removed contour
I have attached the original image and another image for reference showing the position of contour to remove

[image: original image]

[image: Reference image for showing contour position]

Comment: In place of `mask[y:y + h, x:x + w] = 0` simply draw a white filled contour over a copy of the input image to fill a black dot. See cv2.drawContour()

Comment: I have tried that but it will remove many part from the original image as well @fmw42

Comment: @utsavvc I think you did not understand fmw42's comment. Instead of drawing on the `mask` you need to draw on `input_array`  :   `input_array[y:y + h, x:x + w] = (0,0,0)`. Now save `input_array` not `mask`.